# Calculating the determinant of the Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, kerr-metric

I have been trying to calculate the determinant of the Kerr metric (described by equation 11.71, *A First Course in General Relativity: 3rd Edition*, B. Schutz):

$$\begin{align}ds^2 &=-\frac{(\Delta-a^2\sin^2\theta)}{\rho^2}dt^2-2a\frac{2Mr\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}dtd\phi\\&+\frac{(r^2+a^2)^2-a^2\Delta\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}\sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2+\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta}dr^2+\rho^2d\theta^2\end{align}$$

where

$$a=J/M,$$
$$\Delta=r^2-2Mr+a^2,$$
$$\rho^2=r^2+a^2\cos^2\theta.$$

The metric tensor becomes $$g_{\mu\nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
g_{00} & g_{01} & 0 & 0\\
g_{10} & g_{11} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & g_{22} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & g_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and the determinant becomes

$$\begin{align}&\det(g_{\mu\nu})=g_{00}g_{11}g_{22}g_{33}-g_{10}g_{01}g_{22}g_{33}\\
&=-\frac{(\Delta-a^2\sin^2\theta)}{\rho^2}\frac{(r^2+a^2)^2-a^2\Delta \sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}\sin^2\theta\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta}\rho^2-\left(2a\frac{2Mr\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}\right)^2\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta}\rho^2\\
&=-(\Delta-a^2\sin^2\theta)\left((r^2+a^2)^2-a^2\Delta \sin^2\theta\right)\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\Delta}-\frac{(4aMr\sin^2\theta)^2}{\Delta}\end{align}$$

I have not been able to simplify it any further, but I'm certain that there must be a more 'digestable' expression that it could be simplified into.

Comment: This question is about the simplification of algebraic expressions, not about physics.

Comment: I think your $g_{01}$ and $g_{10}$ are too large by a factor of 2.

Comment: The coordinate order is $(t,\phi,r,\theta)$? Is that what the book does? I usually see $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: See eqn. (70) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0622.pdf) for the simplified form.

Comment: see [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/67.html#1) at the end of Output 1

Comment: Did you try writing it as a single fraction and determining whether the denominator divided the numerator?